# How to Create a Ember Project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ember.js

Iam new to ember and i want to create a ember project in visual studio i have referred the ember documents but all  examples is related to npm.so how to create a ember project in VS2012?

**Edit:I** also tried this https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9078967b-525a-469b-bb1a-6dde5e34aabf

Comment: First Google result for "visual studio ember.js" - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9078967b-525a-469b-bb1a-6dde5e34aabf - I don't know how updated this is however.

Comment: I was trying to  make VS2013 work with ember but after few hours I rather switched IDE to webstorm.